How to use dependency injection in MAUI ServiceProvider?
I'm a newbie in .NET MAUI development, and I have a question about use dependency injection in MAUI.
My project is a not very standardized MAUI program, it does not need to be deployed for mobile terminals at present, it only needs to be deployed on Windows (essentially a WPF program, but I want to learn MAUI so brave).
This program will also use relational databases and appsettings.json, although this is not the design specification that MAUI is supposed to follow, but I want to know how I can apply the appsettings.json that I read to each view model in this way, which is how I'm currently designing it.
Step 1: I add an appsettings.json in project and set it to embedded resources and do not copy:

Step 2: I use following code to read the json file and inject into the builder in MauiProgram.cs
public class ServiceContainer
{
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public DashboardViewModel DashboardViewModel => _serviceProvider.GetService<DashboardViewModel>();

    public ServiceContainer()
    {
        var serviceContainer = new ServiceCollection();

        // register view model
        serviceContainer.AddScoped<DashboardViewModel>();

        // register service
        serviceContainer.AddScoped<IFileServices, FileServices>();

        _serviceProvider = serviceContainer.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}

Step 3: in every xaml, I used BindingContext to bind related view model by StaticResource:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"  
             x:Class="Ubisoft.Coffee.Pages.SettingsPage"      
             BindingContext="{Binding SettingsViewModel, Source={StaticResource SeriviceContainer}}"
             Title="SettingsPage">

Step 4: I register static resource in App.xaml that each xaml could use a ServiceContainer:
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />

                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <local:SeriviceContainer x:Key="SeriviceContainer"></local:SeriviceContainer>
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>

My target is want to use IConfiguration to use appsettings.json.
But this method could not use dependency injection, can anyone help me?

Does it answer your question? MAUI: Windows platform reads App.config but Android doesn't

Why did you bind the ViewModel by using StaticResource? If you want to use DI for ViewModel, you may refer to Dependency injection containers.
